# Removing from List with date comparing

Tags: java, list, iterator, refactoring

I have to remove all objects before `param.getFromDateTime` and after `params.getToDateTime`. I did it like this:

```
for (ListIterator<Doc> iterator = doc.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
            if(param.getFromDateTime() != null
              && doc.get(iterator.nextIndex()).getDate().before(params.getFromTime())) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
            if(params.getToDateTime() != null
              && doc.get(iterator.nextIndex()).getDate().after(params.getToDateTime())) {
                iterator.remove();
           }
    }
}
```

Can I do it better and more clear?

Comment: Why do you call `doc.get(iterator.nextIndex())` instead of `iterator.next()` and reusing the returned element? And why do you use 2 nested loops?

Comment: I think you should post this to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two loops and you don't need `ListIterator` either.
Note that the two conditions may be true but that you want remove only one element in any case because invoking twice `remove()` will rise an exception.
You could also extract directly the `date` from the iterated `Doc` object to make it still a little bit clearer :

```
for (Iterator<Doc> iterator = doc.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
      Date date = iterator.next().getDate();

      if( (param.getFromDateTime() != null && date.before(params.getFromTime())) 
          || (params.getToDateTime() != null && date.after(params.getToDateTime()))) {
        iterator.remove();
      }

}
```

Comment: The warning about Exception while calling `remove()` two times is very useful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. I added an additional refactoring.  Finally we don't need `Doc` variable here.

Answer (score 2):

A java-8 aproximation with stream api:

```
List<Doc> docs = ...;
Stream<Doc> stream = docs.stream();
LocalDateTime fromDateTime = param.getFromDateTime();
LocalDateTime toDateTime = param.getToDateTime();
if (fromDateTime != null){
    stream = stream.filter(d -> !d.getDate().before(fromDateTime);
}
if (toDateTime != null){
    stream = stream.filter(d -> !d.getDate().after(toDateTime);
}
docs = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use `List.removeIf` in case you are using Java 8:

```
List<Doc> docs = generateSomeValues(); // this ist just an imaginary filling of the list
// check if the params are not null and remove dates that are not in the given interval
docs.removeIf(doc ->
    (params.getFromTime() != null && doc.getDate().before(params.getFromTime()))
    || (params.getToDateTime() != null && doc.getDate().after(params.getToDateTime()))
);
```